# Having issue with my code : error "none type"

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

1. function that takes two functions f and g, and finds the point of intersection between a and b with the tolerance of eps, in other words, find the point c such that absolute value of f(c) - g(c)

   the above is the question and I am getting "none" as my output

   ```
   #defining two functions

   f1 = lambda x: 2*x + 3
   g1 = lambda x: 3*x - 4

   # making a function called "intersect"
   # a and b is the upper and lower limit
   # eps is the tolerance of the answer
   def intersect(f,g,a,b,eps):
       c1= 0                   #defining c1 (real number) for simplicity                   
       n = 1                   # to limit the number of iteration
      while n <= 1000:
          c1 = (a+b)/2        #using bisection formula
          if abs(f(c1) - g(c1)) < eps or ((b-a)/2)<eps:       # two conditions |f(c)-g(c)| <eps
              break
              return c1
          if f(c1)<=0:        # accd to bisection theorem
              a = c1
          else:
              b = c1         # accd to bisection theorem
          n +=1              # incrementing to limit the iteration
   print(intersect(f1,g1, -10, 10, 0.001))
   ```

Comment: Your `return` statement is after a `break`. Try removing `break`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
   if abs(f(c1)-g(c1)) < eps or ((b-a)/2) < eps:
       break
       return c1
```

The `break` statement exits your `while` loop before a value is returned, and since no other values were returned, the return value for the function is `None`.
Once a value is returned, the function exits, so you don't need a `break` statement.

Comment: okay i checked,
my test case is :
        x = intersect(f1,g1,-10,10,0.001)
        abs(f1(x) -g1(x))<0.001


it should give True but is giving False